# How to get Google sign-in working for Meteor on iOS?

Tags: ios, cordova, meteor, meteor-accounts, google-plus-signin

I'm setting up a Meteor app and using Google sign-in for the first time. This works fine in the web-app version of the app. However, when building the app for iOS, this generates a problem.

I do this:

meteor run ios-device --mobile-server https://myapp.meteorapp.com

Then get this:

Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-googleplus':Error: Variable(s) missing: REVERSED_CLIENT_ID

And

While adding plugin https://github.com/meteor/cordova-plugin-googleplus.git#blabla to Cordova project:
Error: Variable(s) missing: REVERSED_CLIENT_ID

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do 2 things.

1. create a credential
2. add it to your mobile-config.js

Go to the same place you created your webapp credential. Something like this: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=YOURPROJECT

Click the Create Credential button... pick OAUTH... and then pick IOS.

Enter your info... and then 
take that number and paste it into you mobile-config.js file like this:

```
App.configurePlugin('cordova-plugin-googleplus', {
    REVERSED_CLIENT_ID: 'com.googleusercontent.apps.LONGNUMBER'
});
```

[image: click the CREATE credential]

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: As the credentials appear to be specifically for iOS, what happens for Android?

Comment: Good question... I *think* you just create a third credential... but I don't actually know what syntax to use in your mobile-config file to specify one id for each platform.

Comment: App.setPreference() takes a platform parameter... maybe you can use that?

Comment: This guy says:  If you are building a hybrid application (iOS and Android), or an Android application, you have to replace myreversedclientid with the reverse value of Client ID in your Release credential generated on step 3, on Google Developer's Console, this will be: "com.googleusercontent.apps.uniqueId", without quotes https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus

Comment: Thanks. It seems that that plugin helps doing the trick, even if it seems horribly convoluted.